# How to make data annotations work with custom Entity Framework queries

Tags: c#, winforms, data-annotations

I'm using VS 2017 and EF 6.2. I have the following POCO class where I've added the `Display` attribute to the `OR_NAME` property.

```
public partial class ORDERS
{
    public int OR_ROWID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> OR_REFNO { get; set; }

    public string OR_PROD_CODE { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Order Name")]
    public string OR_NAME { get; set; }

    public Nullable<DateTime> OR_DATE { get; set; }

    public virtual CONTACTS_BASE CONTACTS_BASE { get; set; }
    public virtual ORDER_TYPES ORDER_TYPES { get; set; }
}
```

I'm binding my DataGridView to an `IQueryable` and expect my `OR_NAME` column header text to be `Order Name` - however at some cases it does not work and I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or if there is a fix for this.

Below are the scenarios which it works and does not work

Scenario 1: works

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = context.ORDERS.ToList();
```

Scenario 2: does not work

```
 var query = from a in context.ORDERS
             select new
                    {
                         a.OR_ROWID,
                         a.OR_NAME,
                         a.OR_PROD_CODE
                    };

dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Scenario 3: does not work

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = context.ORDERS
                                  .Select(x => new { x.OR_NAME })
                                  .ToList();
```

Any help or suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: In scenario 2 & 3, you are creating anonymous type instances and the anonymous type does not have the `Display` attribute. Create instances of `ORDERS` class instead because it has the attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the `new` keyword used in scenarios 2 and 3, a new object is create of a different type than the class `ORDER`.

When creating these objects from the dynamic types specified the data annotations are not considered as they are of a different type.

Scenario 1 works as the list of objects are still of type `ORDER` and therefore the data annotation remains.